# How to check if uint8_t exists as a type, instead of unsigned char?

Tags: c++, c, embedded

I have two compilers, one that recognizes uint8_t(GCC ARM-EABI), and one that doesn't(Renesas M16 Standard Toolchain).

The Renesas Toolchain is NOT ANSI C compliant, so you can throw out .  So uint8_t, uint16_t,... aren't defined as existing types.

In order to maintain portability, I would like to have the same types(preferably uint8_t, due to the ambiguity of int).

Also my platforms are different size processors(ARM is 32 bit, and Renesas is 16 bit). Causing int to be different values.

Is there a way to check if uint8_t exists as a type?

And if not, declare it(and others uint16_t, uint32_t,...) as a type?

Comment: Does `uint_least8_t` exist in the Renesas toolchain?

Comment: `std::is_same<unsigned char, uint8_t>::value`.

Comment: Make a header that includes <stdint.h> always, and defines these types if the current compiler is Renesas and otherwise does nothing.

Comment: I don't think uint_least8_t exists

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few different ways to deal with this. In an open source project that needs to be portable, the common solution is to have a "configure script", which is run to setup the build system. It would then have something like `HAVE_UINTX_TYPES` that is set or not set in some `config.h` or similar [which was one of the results of the "configure script", and do something like this:

```
#include "config.h"
...
#ifndef HAVE_UINTX_TYPES
#include "uintx_types.h"
#endif
```

In a less "needs to run on almost anything" system, you could solve the same problem by simply have a `-DHAVE_UINTX_TYPES` as part of the flags to the compiler. And since you (presumably) have some part of the build system that sets different compile options, picks a different compiler, etc, for the two different builds, this shouldn't be a big issue to add.

And assuming that you are happy that your `unsigned char` is indeed 8 bits, you could also do have a `uintx_types.h` that contains something like this:

```
typedef unsigned char  uint8_t; 
typedef unsigned short uint16_t;
typedef unsigned long  uint32_t;
```

Another option is to not use `uint8_t` and `uint16_t` etc directly, but have your own definitions [and have these depend on the appropriate build setting for "is it ARM or Renesas", e.g. by using different include options]:

ARM/types.h:

```
typedef unsigned char  u_int8;
typedef unsigned short u_int16;
typedef unsigned int   u_int32;
```

Renesas/types.h:

```
typedef unsigned char  u_int8;
typedef unsigned int   u_int16;
typedef unsigned long  u_int32;
```

Comment: seeing that my platform doesn't support uintN_t  i'll have to implement some sort of detection.  the config script isn't idea, though do to the huge differences in build systems, and there own built in compilers. But I can add a small header file to declare these types for Renesas.  Gwah darn dumb compilers.

Comment: @Ashitakalax:  It is not a matter pf platform support - these types are defined in header files, you can create any header file you wish and if you happen to call it stdint.h, then all your code will be platform *and* toolchain independent.  There is *nothing* in stdint.h that cannot be implemented using a C89 compiler.

Comment: @Ashitakalax: I agree with Clifford - if there isn't a `stdint.h` header from the compiler, then make your own, that's a fine solution.

Answer (score 11):

> Is there a way to check if uint8_t exists as a type?

Use:

```
#include <stdint.h>

#ifdef UINT8_MAX
...
#endif
```

Comment: Suggest expanding this correct answer to deal with the OP's 2nd question "And if not, declare it (...) as a type?"

Comment: turns out my compiler really sucks.  no stdint.h file.

Answer (score 8):

`uint8_t` is not a built-in type, it is defined in stdint.h.  So it is not a matter of the compiler "recognising" uint8_t, but rather simply a case of making stdint.h available.

If your toolchain does not provide stdint.h, you can easily provide your own implementation, using the compiler documentation to determine the built-in types that correspond to the specific sizes. On the toolchain without stdint.h you simply provide your own to the project, on the toolchain with stdint.h you don't.  That way the code (other than stdint.h itself) will be identical across platforms - you don't need to conditionally define uint8_t.

One problem you may come across (on some TI DSP's for example) is that memory may not be 8 bit addressable and a char will be 16 bit (or larger).  In that case uint8_t or indeed any 8 bit integer type will not be supported at all.  A char is always the smallest data type for the specific platform, but may be larger than 8 bit.

Comment: 8 bits are supported, but stdint.h isn't recognized.

Comment: @Ashitakalax: So make one.  You may only need to implement a subset of basic types to compile most code, but you could also write a fully ISO C99 compliant implementation with thr complete range of specialist types and macros:[ref](http://www.ceplusplus.com/reference/cstdint/). [Here's an example implementation for VC++ 6](http://msinttypes.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/stdint.h), it is of course 32bit, but you only need change a few typedefs to suit a 16 bit target.

Comment: yeah i plan to make a file specific this device.  I just wasn't sure if there was easy way to do it without it the extra file.

Comment: @Ashitakalax:  What could be easier than doing it *once* and then using it in all projects thereafter.

Answer (score 4):

If `uint8_t` doesn't exist, it's either because the implementation does not conform to C99, or because it has no type that meets the requirements. The latter probably means `CHAR_BIT > 8` (which is vanishingly rare outside embedded systems).

```
#if __STDC_VERSION__ >= 199901L
#include <stdint.h>
#ifdef UINT8_MAX
// uint8_t exists
#else
// uint8_t doesn't exist in <stdint.h>
#else
// uint8_t probably doesn't exist because this isn't a C99 or better compiler
#endif
```

It's possible for an implementation that doesn't fully conform to C99 to provide `<stdint.h>` and `uint8_t` as an extension. That's difficult to detect, because there's no conditional `#include` directive; a `#include` either includes the requested header or fails.

But you can detect it by going outside the C language, using some kind of configuration script. If this compiles:

```
#include <stdint.h>
uint8_t dummy;
```

then `uint8_t` exists; otherwise it doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

The main point of `uint8_t` is that it won't exist on platforms that don't support an unsigned integral type with exactly 8 bits. If `unsigned char` is acceptable, even though it might be larger than 8 bits, then **don't** use `uint8_t`. There's nothing to be gained by using `unsigned char` on one platform and `uint8_t` on another.

Comment: It also doesn't exist on random platforms that simply hasn't implemented it for some arbitrary other reason - although it's presence is a sign that it works on that architecture, the absence is not proof that the processor isn't 8-bit capable.

Comment: Absence is proof that the implementations is either non-conforming to the C standard or that `CHAR_BIT` is greater than 8.

Comment: @R.. or that the implementation is conforming to C89

Comment: well my platform supports 8 bit unsigned char, but not uint8_t.