# Does C99 mandate a `int64_t` type be available, always?

Tags: c, 64-bit, language-lawyer, c99

Does the C99 standard mandate that a conforming compiler have a 64-bit `int64_t`  defined (and usable)? Or is it optional, and just happens to be defined by all popular compilers? I'm obviously asking specifically about platforms on which the CPU can't process 64-bit values directly, but the question is more general

I can't really figure this out from the [C data types Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types#Fixed-width_integer_types), nor from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5531421/1593077) to a related question.

Comment: Not sure about C99, but `int64_t` is definitely optional in C11, except when it's not. See section 7.20.1.1 of the C11 specification for details.

Comment: @user3386109: Could I trouble you for a link? Also, your phrasing is rather cryptic.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a link. But the draft of the C11 specification is freely available online, and can be found by searching for `N1570`

Comment: [Link to C11 draft](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.20.1.1p3). The types are optional but should be provided if the machine architecture has an appropriate type, and must be provided if some integer type has the same characteristics.

Comment: Anyway, the answer is "no". You cannot count on the types existing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding fixed width integer types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51173366/understanding-fixed-width-integer-types)

Comment: [Are there any platforms where fixed width types (intXX_t) are missing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51590607/995714), [Can stdint's int8_t exist on an architecture that does not have 8-bit bytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15336136/995714), [Understanding fixed width integer types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51173366/995714), [How to check if uint8_t exists as a type, instead of unsigned char?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18131032/995714), [Are the fixed width integer types guaranteed to be typedefs for the standard built in types?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31037764/995714)

Comment: @phuclv: All of that stuff is simply not what I asked.

Comment: definitely yes. They all say that fixed-width integers are not required on systems that can't support them. Only the `least` variant is required

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does the C99 standard mandate that a conforming compiler have a 64-bit
>   int64_t defined (and usable)? Or is it optional, and just happens to
>   be defined by all popular compilers?

The type is optional, in one sense, and conditionally required in a different sense.  Specifically, [C99 says](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#7.18.1.1),

> The typedef name intN_t designates a signed integer type with width N
>   , no padding bits, and a two's complement representation. [...]
>
> These types are optional. However, if an implementation provides
>   integer types with widths of 8, 16, 32, or 64 bits, no padding bits,
>   and (for the signed types) that have a two's complement
>   representation, it shall define the corresponding typedef names.

Thus, `int64_t` is optional in the sense that a conforming implementation is not required to provide any type that exactly matches the characteristics of an `int64_t`, and if it doesn't, then it needn't (indeed, must not, according to another section) provide type `int64_t`.

C99 does specify that there is a type `long long int` whose required minimum range necessitates a representation at least 64 bits wide.  Now it is possible that in some implementation there is no signed integer type *exactly* 64 bits wide (for example, maybe `int` is 24 bits, `long` 48, and `long long` 96), and it is possible that there is a 64-value-bit integer type, but it contains padding bits or is not represented in two's complement.  Such implementations could be fully conforming and yet not define an `int64_t`.  In practice, though, there aren't any such implementations in common use today.

Comment: So can you have a C99-conforming compiler which does not provide `int64_t`? I mean, can, say `long long` have a non-power-of-2 size, or 128 bits, and `int64_t` be missing?

Comment: Yes, @einpoklum, in principle you can.  As I said, "a conforming implementation is not required to provide any type that exactly matches the characteristics of an int64_t, and if it doesn't, then it needn't (indeed, must not [...]) provide type int64_t".  However, in practice, I am not aware of any existing, conforming C99 or C11 implementation that fails to provide `int64_t`.

Answer (score 2):

> Does the C99 standard mandate that a conforming compiler have a 64-bit int64_t defined (and usable)?

No, yet C99 requires `long long` which is at *least* 64-bits.

Further, `int64_t` is very commonly available.  It would be very  unlikely you will encounter a conformant C99 without `int64_t` as it **is required** on nearly all platforms.

> C11dr  7.20.1.1 Exact-width integer types
>   (`int64_t`) .... if an implementation provides integer types with
>   widths of 8, 16, 32, or 64 bits, no padding bits, and (for the signed types) that have a two’s complement representation, it shall define the corresponding typedef names.

The bit width of the processor is not a factor in this functionality - `long long` must exist. If that `long long` (or any standard type is 64-bit 2's compliment), then `int64_t` **must** exist too.   A processer's bit width does affect *performance*.

---

[@R..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54915742/does-c99-mandate-a-int64-t-type-be-available-always/54916000?noredirect=1#comment96598333_54916000) comment emphasizes that a `long long` that takes 64-bits of memory to encode, can, by spec only support the range of [-0x7fff-ffff-ffff-ffff ... +0x7fff-ffff-ffff-ffff], one shy of `int64_t` range of [-0x8000-0000-0000-0000 ... +0x7fff-ffff-ffff-ffff].  Such platforms these days are exceedingly rare, if they exist.

Comment: C does not require `long long` to be 64-bit. `LLONG_MIN` is permitted to be `-0x7fffffffffffffff`, which makes it almost 100 zeptobits short of 64-bit if the implementation makes such a bad choice (and, for practical purposes, 63-bit).

Comment: @R.. Agree "C does not require `long long` to be 64-bit.", that is why the answer has "`long long` which is at _least_ 64-bits.".  It could be wider.  It could have a range as narrow as [-0x7fff-ffff-ffff-ffff ... +0x7fff-ffff-ffff-ffff]

Comment: It doesn't even require it to be "at least 64 bits". it requires it to be at least 63.999999999999999999921... bits. Sorry my first comment was misworded and missing the phrase "at least", but the point was that the "at least" is false due to the backwards provisions for allowing ones-complement, sign/magnitude, and "deficient twos complement" implementations.

Comment: @R.. Since there's no such thing as fractional bits, that's the same thing as "at least 64 bits".

Comment: @Barmar: No, you have to round down if you only want to count whole bits, in which case it's effectively 63-bit (i.e. the largest power-of-two interval that's fully representable in the range is 2^63 in length, not 2^64). One way of thinking of this is that one bit is potentially "not fully usable".

Comment: @R.. Signed types are limited to the common _two’s complement_.  The rare _sign and magnitude_ and _ones’ complement_ optional encoding require a minimal 64-bit encoding as well.  Of course, we are splitting hairs/bits. ;-)

Comment: Note that the next version of the C standard will fix this, mandating full-range twos complement for all integer types. We have SO's own JF Bastien to thank for this! :-)

Comment: @R.. If you require at least 63.9999... bits, and you round down, you'll have less than that many bits and won't be able to encode the full range.

Comment: @R.. Interesting news about next version of the C.  Have an anticipated year?

Comment: I think it will be more focused on very important issues  like trigraphs and so on. Any modernisation attempt will be opposed by IBM (as always) as they have created 60 years ago weird architectures and they want C standard to be implementable on it

Comment: @Barmar: The point is that you cannot represent a full 64-bit range on such an implementation, so if you want to treat `long long` as having power-of-two range, you have to treat it as only being 63-bit. Of course you can treat it as having the full almost-64-bit range, but that's not a 64-bit range and it's incorrect to describe it as such.

Comment: @chux: I think I saw an estimate somewhere but I don't recall where. I've been in contact with jfbastien on and off via Twitter and other channels regarding the proposal and its acceptance, though.

Comment: @R.. My point is how many bits you need to represent the required range. A sign/magnitude representation can't represent the same range as 64-bit two's complement, but it still needs 64 bits to represent that range (63 bits of magnitude, 1 bit of sign).

Comment: @Barmar: Generally when using a type you care about the range of values it can represent, not (or at least more than) the amount of storage it requires. If you're talking about storage you'd also count padding bits.

Comment: @R.. Of course. But you were the one who said "it requires it to be at least 63.999999999999999999921... bits", which seems to be talking about the amount of storage.

Comment: @Barmar: Rather it's talking about a space of possible values. Fractional bits make sense when talking about entropy/possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

There are three sets of [integer types](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.20.1):

- `intN_t` — such as `int64_t` and their unsigned counterparts; these exact types may not be available.
- `int_leastN_t` — such as `int_least64_t`; types `int_least8_t`, `int_least16_t`, `int_least32_t` and `int_least64_t` and their unsigned counterparts are required — other types are optional.
- `int_fastN_t` — such as `int_fast64_t`; types `int_fast8_t`, `int_fast16_t`, `int_fast32_t` and `int_fast64_t` are required (they're the fastest type with at least the given width).

The standard also requires support for `long long`, and the minimum acceptable range for `long long` requires at least 64 bits (see [§5.2.4.1 Sizes of integer types `<limits.h>`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.4.2.1)).  Therefore, the standard can legitimately demand support for the 'least' and 'fast' types at 64 bits or more — it also requires that to support `long long`.

There used to be computers with 36-bit words, and others with 60-bit words.  Both of these would struggle to provide (basically, "couldn't provide") the exact width types, but can easily provide support for the 'least' and 'fast' types.

The standard does not mandate the 'exact width types' — see [§7.20.1.1 Exact-width integer types ¶3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.20.1.1p3):

> These types are optional. However, if an implementation provides integer types with widths of 8, 16, 32, or 64 bits, no padding bits, and (for the signed types) that have a two's complement representation, it shall define the corresponding typedef names.

Comment: `There used to be computers with 36-bit words, and others with 60-bit words.`  New standard should forget 40-50 years old computers. And yes there will not be conforming C21 compilers for them. Some standard fanatics would have a heart attack - there will be no way of writing portable code for the ferrite memory machines. End of the world. The life will be senseless.

Comment: What was faintly relevant twenty years ago is not so relevant now.  In 1999, there were at least some machines of those types still running outside of computer museums.  These days, not so much.

Comment: Also, there are DSP-class machines with `CHAR_BIT` of 16.  They have problems with `int8_t`, but not the other types.

Comment: Note that while `int_least64_t` is mandated to exist, it need not have range at least as large as `int64_t` would if it existed. `int_least64_t` is permitted to only go down to -2^63+1 rather than all the way down to -2^63. This will be fixed in the next edition of the C standard. See *7.20.2.2 Limits of minimum-width integer types*.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler no one writes portable code for them. If someone tries to use uint8_t on them, should find an easier job

Answer (score 1):

### No, C99 does not mandate an `int64_t` type.

(Thanks @user3386109, @Clifford)

An `int64_t` type is not required to be available. Quoting the [C99 standard draft document N1256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf):

> 7.18.11.1  Exact-width integer  types
>
> 1. The  typedef  name int **N**_t designates  a  signed  integer  type etc. etc.
>      ...
> 2. These  types  are optional. However,  if  an  implementation  provides  integer  types with widths  of  ... 64  bits... that  have  a two’s complement
>      representation... it shall define the corresponding typedef name.

But see @chux and @JohnBollinger's answers about `long long` having 64 bits.

Comment: Using the word "probably" does not sound like a definite answer.

Comment: Yuu could have as easily referenced the C99 draft and been definitive.  http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf